# I get this error on my production server, but the application works locally just fine

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

> Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the
>   database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations
>   to create the database and its tables, for example by running the
>   'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

Can anyone explaing why?

Comment: This blog post seems to offer a workaround: [ef6-if-migrations-are-enabled-cannot-createdatabaseifnotexists](https://softwaremechanik.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/ef6-if-migrations-are-enabled-cannot-createdatabaseifnotexists/)

Comment: What initializer are you using in PROD? Have migrations been applied to PROD?

Comment: I am snot sure if I have applied migrations to the PROD. I just dragged all files from local server to the production server and changed the connection string to the production database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dev system is working and prod is not, you can generate a script to bring them back in sync:

```
update-database -Script –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase
```

This will create an idempotent script that will test what has been applied and what hasn't. Now use SQL Server Management Studio to apply that script.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#idempotent

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing this yesterday and it worked. Thanks thought

Comment: Also before this I forgot to set my initial Catalog to the database, and forgot to set my default database user to the correct database. But once I did that I did the above and it worked great. Thanks!